# Opening Gmail's Compose page opens up in the whole page - need to open in an iframe how!

Tags: javascript, gmail, google-apps

I would like to open up the compose page for gmail in an iframe on my google app based application. I have a simple modal window set up which has an iframe set up and I wish to open up teh gmail compose page within it. The link I use is:

```
https://mail.google.com/a/YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&source=mailto
```

However for some reason the page always opens in a new window even when called from an iframe infact I believe its running some javascript to destroy all container frames. Is there a way to work around this - what are the fc and tf variable btw? Changing them doesn't help at all. How do I set it up so I can open the Gmail compose page in a modal window i.e iframe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that Gmail breaks out of the frame using JavaScript.  I'm not sure if there is anything you can do about this.

Is there an API for Gmail?  If there is, you can use it to build your own dialog to create messages through the API.

Comment: Its pretty much what you said - Gmail seems to use a frame busting script which automatically sets Gail to occupy the top frame if its..'framed' - guess I'll have to make do with a popup window for this then...